# Translating #!/bin/ksh date conversion function into #!/bin/sh

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I used this ksh function for converting "1-Jan-2011" format to "1.1.2011."

```
#!/bin/ksh

##---- function to convert 3 char month into numeric value ----------
convertDate()
{
    echo $1 | awk -F"-" '{print $1,$2,$3}' | read day mm yyyy ## split the date arg
    typeset -u mmm=`echo $mm` ## set month to uppercase
    typeset -u months=`cal $yyyy | grep "[A-Z][a-z][a-z]"` ## uppercase list of all months
    i=1 ## starting month
    for mon in $months; do ## loop thru month list
    ## if months match, set numeric month (add zero if needed); else increment month counter
    [[ "$mon" = "$mmm" ]] && typeset -xZ2 monthNum=$i || (( i += 1 ))
    done ## end loop
    echo $day.$monthNum.`echo $yyyy | cut -c3-` ## return all numeric date format ddmmyyyy
}
```

But I need to use this function with #!/bin/sh. So I tried rewriting it...

```
#!/bin/sh

##---- function to convert 3 char month into numeric value ----------
convertDate()
{
    echo $1 | awk -F"-" '{print $1,$2,$3}' | read day mm yyyy ## split the date arg
    echo $mm #IT SEEMS LIKE THE PROBLEM IS IN THE PREVIOUS LINE, BECAUSE THIS VARIABLE IS EMPTY IN #!/bin/sh, BUT IF YOU CHANGE IT TO #!/bin/ksh EVERYTHING SEEM TO BE FINE, THEN FUNCTION WORKS CORRECTLY.
    mmm=`echo $mm | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`
    months=`cal $yyyy | grep "[A-Z][a-z][a-z]" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`
    i=1 ## starting month
    for mon in $months; do ## loop thru month list
    ## if months match, set numeric month (add zero if needed); else increment month counter
    if [ "$mon" = "$mmm" ]; then
        monthNum=`printf '%02d' $i`
    else
        i=`expr $i + 1`
    fi
    done ## end loop
    echo $day.$monthNum.`echo $yyyy | cut -c3-` ## return all numeric date format ddmmyyyy
}

convertDate "20-May-2010"
```

But it doesn't work (read the UPPERCASE comment in the last script) :(

Help!

Comment: Why do you need it to run with /bin/sh ? On Solaris 10 and older, this shell isn't designed to be used for new scripts but only there to guarantee compatibility with legacy ones. Edit: sorry, I just noticed you seem to use Linux, not Solaris so this comment doesn't apply.

Comment: No, I do use Solaris (actually our clients use it, and I'm writing this script for them). But I MUST use /bin/sh (so my boss says, although I disagree). Anyway, geekosour's post helped. Thank You for Your efforts as well :)

Comment: If your boss want you to use sh and not ksh, then pick the POSIX compliant bourne shell on Solaris: `#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that whether the `read` command runs in a subshell due to the pipeline depends on exactly which shell `/bin/sh` is; you will get one behavior from `bash` and another from legacy UNIX (e.g. Solaris) `/bin/sh`.  Use `set` instead.

```
set -- `echo $1 | awk -F"-" '{print $1,$2,$3}'`
```

although I would probably write

```
oIFS="$IFS"
IFS=-
set -- $1
IFS="$oIFS"
```

Comment: GREAT!!!                                                         for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){ cout<<"Thank You!\n"; }                 I know this "thanks" is C++, not in shell, but I think it'l doo :D